# Should I have ECA before submitting EOI in SINP?

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry, pr

I have lodged and submitted an EOI a week ago, and received an ITA the day after.

The problem is, I hadn’t ECA and Professional Status(licensure) at the time I was submitting the EOI but I mistakenly said I have them!

Although, I am pretty sure that I can acquire both in 60 days period that I have been given to submit my application, I am worried if it is considered act of cheating or dishonesty.

So, Should I ignore my ITA and apply again whenever I had both ECA and licensure documents in hand?

I have already send an email to immigration office and asked them this question, they havn’t replied yet.

**ECA** : Education Credential Assessment

**EOI** : Expression Of Interest

**ITA** : Invitation To Apply

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained ECA, EOI, SINP, and ITA.  As it is I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for trying to help, but I think those who know the answer should already know what those abbrivations stand for.Again thanks for your comment

Comment: I think you will be okay. if you're confident enough that you will get both ECA and whatever license you are talking about in 60 days, you should be okay. I have seen cases where people are not able to get medical appointments and are still issued an ITA. CIC tells them to go ahead and apply even without medicals and submit the medicals when they have it. However that's a different case. I would say apply only if you are sure you will get it in 60 days.

Comment: @DipenShah your answer turn out to be true! If you like to add an answer, I would gladly accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, people knowing the answer might know what those things are, but one of the purposes of this site is to help others, some of whom might be in an earlier stage of the process and might therefore benefit from learning what these things mean.  Thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: @phoog Yes, you are completely right, Thanks for noticing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will be okay. if you're confident enough that you will get both ECA and whatever license you are talking about in 60 days, you should be okay. I have seen cases where people are not able to get medical appointments and are still issued an ITA. CIC tells them to go ahead and apply even without medicals and submit the medicals when they have it. However that's a different case. I would say apply only if you are sure you will get it in 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

Immigration office has just responded, they said it is ok to send ECA and licensure to them later.

Comment: You should get that in writing.

Comment: @ouflak what do you mean? Like as a proof or mean?!